# How come Naruto's Chakra responds to Wood Elements?

Tags: naruto

Till now it's shown that Naruto is good in Wind Element alone but Naruto's Kyuubi chakra affected the Wood Style technique used by White Zetsu and even Captain Yamato's Wood Style.

> *If that's the case, then why can't Naruto use Wood Element technique?*
> *Why does Kyuubi chakra affect the Wood element alone?*

Comment: The kyuubi chakra's life force affected the wood!

Comment: Its the 'Yang' part of kurama doing the trick. It has great life-force which naturally affects the wood release technique. Its very hard to control the wood release since it requires very strong life force. When a wood release user gets close/direct contact with naruto's kyuubi chakra mode, they are not able to control it. http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Wood_Release

Comment: @RikuduSennin Thanks for the info!!!!! +1 to ur answer!!!!!!

Comment: Kakashi doesn't know this? ;)

Comment: @InfantPro'Aravind' my bad!!!!! but now i know it thanks to you guys :)

Comment: @Kakashi, was just kidding, even I didn't know before running through your post ..

Comment: @InfantPro'Aravind' ok :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[From the following Naruto Wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Yang_Release)

> Whenever Naruto is in Nine-Tails Chakra Mode, Wood Release techniques
>   will react to the Yang chakra's life-giving properties and mature into
>   full-grown trees within a matter of seconds, either by contact or
>   close range.This was also shown to have the same effect on White
>   Zetsu Army clones, whose genetic make-up is similar to that of
>   plants.

Thus, Naruto himself doesn't directly control the effects his yang chakra has on the wood element or the white zetsu.

Also,

> The Yang Release (陽遁, Yōton; Viz "Light Style") techniques, based on
>   the physical energy that governs vitality, can be used to breathe life
>   into form.

Thus, Naruto is not explicitly using the wood element technique, as with the first hokage, yamato or the white zetsu, rather it's the yang element chakra that is resonating in the wood elelemt that provides the wood element the vitality to grow.